# can someone please tell me the difference between < << and <<<, or show me where to find this information

Tags: linux, bash, unix, grep

None of the notes for my class have this information and I absolutely cannot find it on google. any help would be appreciated.

edit: for clarity here are some examples

grep blah < foobar.txt

grep blah << foobar.txt

grep blah <<< foobar.txt

Comment: Try googling for `bash redirect`.

Comment: It's all in `man bash`.

Comment: (...which is why you're not getting a good answer from me -- happy to answer things that are at least modestly obscure, or where there's some kind of evidence of a good-faith effort to find an answer yourself, but that's very much not present here).

Comment: so the man page for bash? i have honestly been searching google for quite some time.

Comment: Just say "what youre looking for is in the bash man pages" then i would say "oh thanks i didnt know that existed"

i found my answer thank you

Answer (score 1):

- `<` is use for redirection, see http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Redirection
- `<<` is use for *here-docs* `cat <<EOF` followed by several lines of text, followed by the literal string EOF on a new line, NOT indented. The portion between the EOFs is passed to the command as standard input. If 'EOF' is 'quoted', substitutions WON'T be done; otherwise they are. See <<- for the indented variety.
- `<<<` is use for *here-string* Similar to here documents: The word after <<< and a newline are passed to the standard input of a command. Syntax: ''command <<< "some sentence"'' (Like ''echo "some sentence" | command'', but without the overhead of the subshell)

Some good docs :

- `man bash`
- http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ